# Better practice to check rights in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, http, backend

I have a Laravel project and I'm building API. I've got into situation where I don't know how to do better.
There is some routes:

```
Route::middleware('task')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/task/{id}', [TaskController::class, 'show'])->name('api.task')->where('id', '\d+');
    Route::get('/task/{id}/comments', [TaskController::class, 'getComments'])->name('api.task.comments')->where('id', '\d+');
    Route::get('/task/{id}/time', [TaskController::class, 'getElapsedTime'])->name('api.task.elapsedTime')->where('id', '\d+');
    Route::get('/task/{id}/history', [TaskController::class, 'getHistory'])->name('api.task.history')->where('id', '\d+');
    Route::post('/task/edit', [TaskController::class, 'edit'])->name('api.task.edit');
    Route::delete('/task/delete/{id}', [TaskController::class, 'delete'])->name('api.task.delete');

    Route::post('/task/comment/create', [TaskController::class, 'createComment'])->name('api.task.comment.create');
});
Route::post('/task/comment/edit', [TaskController::class, 'editComment'])->name('api.task.comment.edit');
```

Some of these routes covered by "task" middleware, which checks user rights to access the "task" by `task_id` parameter. Now I have to implement handler for route '/task/comment/edit', which will allow user to edit his comment. To edit that field it's enough to pass `comment_id` parameter in request, but it means that I have to duplicate some part of code from "task" middleware to check if user have rights to do that. Or it is better to pass additional parameter `task_id` and don't give a ***?
Please don't scold me, I'am a beginner :)

Middleware code:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
if($request-\>isMethod('GET') || $request-\>isMethod('DELETE')) {
$params = $request-\>route()-\>parameters();
$taskId = $params\['id'\];
} else {
$taskId = $request-\>post('id') ?: $request-\>post('task_id');
}
if(empty($taskId)) {
return \\Response::error('No "task_id"', $request-\>route());
}

        $user = $request->user();
        if(!$user->hasTask($taskId)) {
            return \Response::error('Forbidden', [], 403);
        }
    
        $task = \App\Models\Task::find($taskId);
        if(empty($task)) {
            return \Response::error('No such task found');
        }
    
        if($request->has('project_id')) {
            $projectId = $request->post('project_id');
            if(!$user->hasProject($projectId)) {
                return \Response::error('Forbidden', [], 403);
            }
        }
    
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Comment: if all you do is check `$user->id == $task->user_id` you can make a generic method that checks ownership of any model like: `isset($model->user_id) && $user->id == $model->user_id`

Comment: Why not just use [policies](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#creating-policies) for authorization? Middleware is a weird choice.

Answer (score 0):

I have some comments:
Route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api', 'as' => 'api.', 'middleware' => ['api_authorized']], function () {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'task', 'as' => 'task.'], function () {
        Route::get('show/{id}', [TaskController::class, 'show'])->name('show');
        Route::get('create', [TaskController::class, 'create'])->name('create');
        Route::get('/', [TaskController::class, 'index'])->name('create');
    }
}
```

In view you can get route:

```
{{ route('api.task.create') }}
{{ route('api.task.index') }}
{{ route('api.task.show', ['id' => 1]) }}
```

In my personal opinion: When check the user has the task, i usually check in request validate: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#creating-form-requests

Hope it helps you!!!